# Phonegap IOS toolbar

Tags: ios, cordova, uitoolbar

I am developing an iOS app using phonegap. I need to create a UIToolbar to show some icons at top of the app as in Facebook app.

Is there any phonegap plugin available?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you should look up PhoneGap docs instead of asking here.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I did check the phonegap site and phonegap plugins site, but couldnt find any useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

https://code.google.com/p/phonegap-extensions/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fphonegap_js_extensions

p.s. It's the first result from Google result of " uinavigationbar button phonegap "

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/XVru2zgB_yc

Comment: Navigation bar will not suffice for this. In NavigationBar, you can add leftbutton, right button and only one middle item, either a button or text. Otherwise we have to customize the component to contain UISegmentedControl or a toolbar as sub view to contain multiple icons in middle. Thats why I went to use UITollbar itself directly.

Comment: then you probably need to modify the component to add UISegmentedControl at the middle, or use native app instead of PhoneGap. PhoneGap is for simple apps only.